# Browse dll functions and classes in a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, vmware

I have written a web service in C#. I am working with vmware.vim.dll file for vmware API's.
I need to expose the methods in this dll through my web service.

So far I have referenced the dll in my IDE and have been able to use the DEFINED methods. by define I mean the methods that have been written explicitly e.g:

[web method]
Method goes here....

But the dll has many methods and it is not feasible to expose them one by one. So I was wondering if there is any better way for exposing the methods and types of the dll.

Cheers.

Comment: You may want to repost your question as "browsing all functions from a D.L.L.", since is a separate task from make them available to a web service.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the Topic of question. I also would like to expose the classes (types) as well. I would appreciate if any help is provided.

Comment: I thin VMWare View already offers the kind of functionality you are trying to create.

Comment: I looked up vmware view. I couldnt find any functionality that would help me with this issue. Basically what I am looking for is so that I dont have to write all the methods in DLL again in my code. Anything that can browse through the dll and get all the functions and classes and when I publish my webservice those functions and classes are available to the clients using the web service.

Comment: @alex jones You may want to search internet with: c++ reflection dll

Comment: I believe this is something that can not be done. It would have been nice to have that functionality. Thanks umlcat but I cant really start reading up on C++ . plus I am not an experience programmer. I was looking for a head start here.. cheers